# A question for English.SE? "oft evil will shall evil mar"

Tags: discussion, status-completed, scope

I don't agree with closing https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/36879/what-does-theodens-quote-in-the-two-towers-oft-evil-will-shall-evil-mar-mean as "too localised" - but I also don't think it really is an SF&F question.

Perhaps move it to English.SE?

Answer (score 2):

I've had a chat with one of their mods and sent it over. She wasn't 100% sure how it would do there, so it's up to their community to reject the migration or not.

Comment: Seems to have done well. 8 upvotes, 1 answer with 18 upvotes

Comment: It arrived there with +5 and the answer at +13, so it's only gotten +3/+5 over there, but yes it seems to be fine.